# ffmpeg creating gif from images, how to prevent loop?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I'm creating gifs from a small group of images. Currently the gif loops by default. I've been trying variations of -loop in the ffmpeg command, but the gif still loops. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Basic syntax](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#gif-2) is

```
ffmpeg -i images%d {-other-options} -loop -1 out.gif
```

Comment: I had to remove first few frames and therefore ffmpeg threw error because my 4-digit indexing did not start from zero anomore. Fixed by `ffmpeg -start_number 65 -i images%4d.png -loop 1 out.gif`